# Removing cookies while logout in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, authentication, logout

I am working on Login module of iOS application. While login using some username and password, I am getting the user profile as response and status as Login success. In that time am saving login status in NSUserDefaults.

After Logout button clicked, I am setting login status as false in `NSUserDefaults`. But again logging in another login id, I am getting the response as "already logged in". I have to remove any cookies in iOS ?
This is my sample code

```
@IBAction func Login(sender: AnyObject) {

    var mode:NSString = "signin"
    var useremail:NSString = "bbbbbb@ffffff.net"
    //var usermobile:NSString = txtEmail.text
    var pwd:NSString = "123456"//"kKAOWX33zUDlcUpptZOoQA%3D%3D"
    var decrypt:Int = 0//1

    var postString = "http://myaccount.ddddddddd.com/network/sdasdasdasdsh.aspx?"

    var postData = NSString(format:"mode=signin&useremail=%@&pwd=%@&userauth=PPZGySCKmspQ56iALuPpvw==&Decrypt=%d&App=1",useremail,pwd,decrypt)
    var dataExample : NSData = NSData()

    dataExample = postData.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

    var postRequest:NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: postString)!)

    postRequest.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    postRequest.HTTPBody = dataExample

    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(postRequest, queue: NSOperationQueue .mainQueue()){ (response : NSURLResponse!, data : NSData!, error : NSError!) -> Void in

        if data != nil && data.length != 0
        {
            println()
            var asyncError = NSError?()
            print(asyncError)

            var strin:NSString = NSString(bytes: data.bytes, length: data.length, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

            var jsonValue: NSDictionary? = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options:NSJSONReadingOptions(), error: nil) as? NSDictionary
            NSLog("Result %@",jsonValue!)
            self.loginButton.setTitle("Logout", forState: UIControlState())


        }

}
```

Please help me to solve this.

Comment: Can you please provide some code how you store and delete the status of the login? how do you detect that a user is still logged in? the system by itself stores nothing if you don't tell it to. cookies are only set in webview by the websites.

Comment: @palme i have edited my questions.

Comment: *tips : Never write huge methods like this , its really bad practice , it will get hard to debug , always split it into smaller chunk of codes that could be reused . :)

Comment: are you getting response from the external third party that you are plugged into ?? they might be having cookies ??

Comment: yes am getting from server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the following answer

```
 postRequest.HTTPShouldHandleCookies = false
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it ....

```
 if status == true{

        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(false, forKey: "LoginStatus")

        var mode:NSString = "signin"
        var useremail:NSString = "xxxxx@yyyyy.net"
             ................................
       blah blah blah  go to the end line now 

            var jsonValue: NSDictionary? = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options:NSJSONReadingOptions(), error: nil) as? NSDictionary
            NSLog("Result %@",jsonValue!)
            self.loginButton.setTitle("Logout", forState: UIControlState())
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "LoginStatus")
```

//// here you are setting the bool value of LoginStatus which keeps it login always no matter what
            }

Comment: i just added sample code.But am resetting my NSUserDefaults.But still am getting the response as "already logged in" from my server.Is this any server issue

Comment: Im not able to make sense what you are trying to do here , Can you tell me in brief what exactly If block is doing and else block is doing?

Comment: and in beginning of the if block you have set the boolValue of loginStatus to be false and in the end of if block itself you have again you have set the loginStatus to be true , which makes it always logged in ?

Comment: that way the else block will never be executed?

Comment: You have hard coded the username and password ?? which when login button pressed only that user will login all the time?

Comment: in browser when i am loading login api first time, am getting response as "logged in success".But when I am refreshing the same api in browser,am getting the response as "already logged in".But after removing cookies,am getting the response as "logged in success".so how to do in our ios code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84449/discussion-between-sriram-hegde-and-madhumitha).

Comment: Hope you are getting  "already logged in" from server. You got nothing to do. You may ask server team to publish a logout service call. App should call logout service while user taps the logout.

Answer (score 0):

For NSUserDefaults after setting your variable True or False any time write below line after setting it . . .

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Because NSUserDefaults every time required synchronize with the app.